# binary tree doesn't rebuild from file

Tags: c++, codeblocks

I'm new on data structures and we were assigned to make a guessing game using binary tree implementation. I have accomplished the program flow without file implementation. I have saved the binary tree preorderly on an external file now I have problem in rebuilding tree from file 
in my file I have:

> Is it Angel Locsin?:#Neneng B?Is it Sam Pinto? ##White Beauty?Is it
>   Marian Rivera? ##HotandSexy?Is it Cristine Reyes? ###

The "#" is for a NULL node.

I have also my code. I follow the algorithm of what my professor gave me. I searched on the internet and gave me same algorithm as of what my prof said. My problem is on every third non-null data the program crashes. I think the main reason of crashing is a node that was not set to null after the third non-null data is inserted. If so, how could I set it to NULL so that my program will not crash.I assigned the data from file into array of strings and set a "\0" at the last index of array.

```
void read(node *temp)
{
    while(array[j]=="#")
        j++;

    if(array[j]=="\0")
        return;

    node *nNode;
    nNode = new node;
    nNode->yes=NULL;
    nNode->no=NULL;
    nNode->data=array[j];
    j++;
    temp=nNode;
    read(temp->yes);
    read(temp->no);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the definition of your read function. I guess the idea is that "temp" is an output parameter of type "node*". But this is not what you have written.
You need to have a pointer or a reference to the "node*" parameter like e.g. so:

`void read(node** temp)`

Then adjust the rest of the code such that is compiles by proper (de)referencing. This should solve your crash.